# Is it a good idea to develop a SharePoint 2010 solution under Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint-2010

SharePoint 2010 is supported on Win 7 x64, but is it really a good idea to develop under this kind of standalone environment, when the developed solution is expected to be deployed on a Win 2K8 R2 farm?

Comment: guess the answer heavily depends on the type of solution that is being developed.

Answer (score 2):

Officially it is *not supported* on Windows 7 but it's allowed / ok for development purposes (which is already a good candidate to say officially "no")

[image: not supported warning]

The biggest reasons why I usually say no to that kind of environment if one asks for my opinions :

- can only be installed as “stand alone”, which is the worst kind of installation (completely automated but also completely unrealistic). No SharePoint expert will ever suggest a standalone installation on production. Why the hell should we develop on a “stand alone mode” single server farm that is completely unrelated to the target environment ?
- cannot know if it’s environment related when something is / seems broken (eg : taxonomy service provisioning, broken due to environment or code issue ? -> no time to do Windows 7 + SharePoint 2010 cohabitation issues debugging on corporate projects
- when Arpan Shah, Director of SharePoint tools & technlogie says that there are limitations, I guess he knows them better than anyone else : http://reddevnews.com/articles/2010/06/02/sharepoint-qa-arpan-shah.aspx. Since theses limitations have not been fully listed (outside of the user profile service), I better not waste my time wondering if the issue I am facing is related to a limitation / environment gotcha.

The reason why I say "might be ok"

- Prototyping / Client OM development / Middle Tier developments / not so complex solution developments are the kind of configuration / development on which a Windows 7 installation might be pretty handy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing for SharePoint 2010 on a Windows 7 box for about 10 months. I have not encountered any issues by now.

The only issue I know of is that the "User Profile Service" is not supported under Windows 7.

There is an official installation guide by Microsoft:

[Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx)

What kind of issues do you expect?

Comment: I expect issues regarding User Profile Service, Search configuration, Access rights as the system accounts used in both environments are not exactly the same...

Comment: Since you are not deploying your whole development environment to the live server, but only the solution package there should not be any issues regarding user accounts. As long as your setup conforms best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute ASP.NET for SharePoint 2010 and ask the question:

> [ASP.NET] is supported on Win 7 x64, but is it really a good idea to develop under this kind of standalone environment, when the developed solution is expected to be deployed on a Win 2K8 R2 farm?

I can't imagine anyone answering "no" when the question is phrased that way. It is the same with SharePoint (after all, SharePoint is just a framework library built on top of ASP.NET).

A SharePoint solution package contains different types of files: XML files, ASPX pages, DLLs, images, CSS files, etc. Other than the DLLs, these files are text and binary files that are portable to any Windows environment. And just like the DLLs compiled in a ASP.NET project, the DLLs from your SharePoint project will work perfectly fine on the server even when compiled on Windows 7.